# Can I autorun bootrec /fixboot during boot. I have to run fixboot after every power outage or hard reset

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

Everytime there is a power outage or hard reset on my Win 10 system on a SSD I have insert installation media, go into command prompt and run bootrec /fixboot. it fixes my blue screen of death eveytime but is getting old. Can I automate this into a bootable USB? any tricks?

Comment: ...I'm rather more concerned that you have to run it at all... that's far from normal.

Comment: did you try sfc /scannow after a successful boot-up?